# Is the adjectival form "to be concatenated" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives

I have the following sentence:

> Fetch the transformations which need to be concatenated.

Is the following adjectival form of *which need to be concatenated* correct?

> Fetch the to be concatenated transformations.

Are there any more (even more succinct?) variants?

Comment: *Fetch the transformations to be concatenated.* It's exactly as succinct as the version with the adjective in front, and it sounds much better. I'll leave the grammatical analysis of this version to other people.

Comment: The second sounds like patentese, those convoluted noun phrases that are often seen in patent claims. They're practically never seen outside such legal documents, and most English readers would probably consider them confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original sentence has a simple, if wordy, structure

> Fetch [verb] the transformations [direct object] which need to be concatenated [adjectival clause modifying direct object].

Your suggested alternative is arguably right with a slight modification

> Fetch [verb] the *to-be-concatenated* [adjectival infinitive construction modifying direct object] transformations [direct object]

While the verb phrase *to be concatenated* can be used without creating a single term by using a hyphen, it would be very clumsy if used as an adjectival phrase before the noun it modifies.  When used in that fashion, the verb *fetch* is followed by another verb form *to be* that seems to be veering in a different direction. While it makes sense when complete, it is a bit hard to follow. In print, with hyphens, it is a little easier to immediately understand.

However, Peter Shor's suggestion of leading with the noun is *much* easier to follow.

Comment: I find this quite interesting, as the question arose, becuase in german (my mother tongue) such a preceding adjectival construction is rather common: "Hole die _zu verknüpfenden_ Transformationen." (the literal translation would be _aneinanderzuhängenden_) And I was not sure about the english aequivalent.

Comment: A preceding adjectival construction is not so uncommon: *The soon-to-be president was ...* It is the combination of a verb followed by an infinitive (for verbs that don't take infinitives) that is distracting.